# Find all the angles between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$ which satisfy the equation.

Tags: trigonometry

Find all the angles between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$ which satisfy the equation $$\tan 3x-3 \sin 30^\circ=0$$

I tried searching for examples but didn't get any. Please teach me how to solve such problems. At least tell me what steps/methods I gotta do.

I need morrreeee perfect answers? anyone?

Comment: Just the verifiy, inside the sine, is that 30° or is that supposed to be $3x$ ? If it is sin30° then just replace that by 0.5 and isolate the tangent.

Comment: @imranfat yeah it is $30^\circ$....okay lemme try. Thanks.

Comment: You won't get nice answers, you will need to round.

Comment: @imranfat okiee :)

Comment: @imranfat okay I got $x$....uhhh what should I do next?

Comment: tan3x has a period of 60° becaus tanx has period 180°. So you need to add multiples of 60° to your answer to satisfy that interval in your question

Comment: ps. I need to go now...